# Por qué me sale el error "cannot read property 'length' of undefined" cuando uso la siguiente función

Tags: javascript

En este código estoy creando 2 funciones. En la primera declaro los sueldos y luego deseo sumar los sueldos en la segunda función. No sé que pude haber hecho mal. El error que aparece es: cannot read property 'length' of undefined" cuando llamo a la función **sumaSueldos();**

```
function creaVectorSueldo(){
        let sueldos = new Array(2);
        for (var i = 0; i < sueldos.length; i++) {
            let sueldosIngresados = parseInt(prompt('Ingrese sueldo: ',''));
            sueldos[i] = sueldosIngresados;
        }
        return;
    }

    let recibeSueldos = creaVectorSueldo();



    function sumaSueldos(){

        let sumaSueldosTotal = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < recibeSueldos.length; i++) {
            sumaSueldosTotal = sumaSueldosTotal + recibeSueldos[i];
         }
         document.write("La suma de los sueldos es: "+sumaSueldosTotal); 
    }

sumaSueldos();
```

Comment: En tu función `creaVectorSueldo()` no retornas nada, el `return;` esta solo

Comment: Qué deberia retornar en ese caso para que funcione Cesar? Mi idea es sumar todos los sueldos ingresados por el usuario.

Comment: deberias retornar la variable sueldos, `return sueldos;`

Comment: Funcionó!, tienes toda la razón, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se presenta porque en la función `creaVectorSueldo()` te falta retornar la variable `sueldos` que contiene lo ingresado por el usuario.

```js
function creaVectorSueldo(){
  let sueldos = new Array(2);
  for (var i = 0; i < sueldos.length; i++) {
    let sueldosIngresados = parseInt(prompt('Ingrese sueldo: ',''));
    sueldos[i] = sueldosIngresados;
  }
  return sueldos;
}

let recibeSueldos = creaVectorSueldo();

function sumaSueldos(){

  let sumaSueldosTotal = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < recibeSueldos.length; i++) {
    sumaSueldosTotal = sumaSueldosTotal + recibeSueldos[i];
  }
  document.write("La suma de los sueldos es: "+sumaSueldosTotal); 
}

sumaSueldos();
```